# Seaborn: How to handle gap between historic and forecasted values?

Tags: python, regression, seaborn

I have the problem explaining a gap between the historic data and the forecast.
The blue is the historic. And the orange is the lin lin regression forecast with future values.

Dataframe df is the training dataset with columns year, pax, RealGDPLP.
Dataframe FutureValCPs has the columns year and RealGDPLP.

How do you explaing that it is not continuous (in other cases it is)?
The OLS results are attached. Anything which gives an indication?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no data, no code and no details about the graphical engine applied to produce your plot it's going to be hard to be absolutely certain. But your forecasts seem perfectly fine compared to your historical data in that it at the very least predicts a smooth future increase in your values. If the blue line represents your entire dataset, there's really not much more that can be said using OLS.

The reason why there's a gap in your plot, is that the two lines in your plot are two different lines and don't share a common timestamp in the transition between historical and forecasted values. There are ways to *visually* remedy this, but as I've mentioned I have no idea how you've estimated the model or produced this plot.

**Edit: Extended answer based on more information from OP:**

This should resemble your issue with regards to the plot:

[image]

I'm *assuming* that the following dataframe will represent your situation:

```
            historic  forecast
dates                         
2020-01-01       1.0       NaN
2020-01-02       2.0       NaN
2020-01-03       3.0       NaN
2020-01-04       3.0       NaN
2020-01-05       6.0       NaN
2020-01-06       4.0       NaN
2020-01-07       8.0       NaN
2020-01-08       NaN       6.0
2020-01-09       NaN       7.0
2020-01-10       NaN       8.0
2020-01-11       NaN       9.0
2020-01-12       NaN      10.0
2020-01-13       NaN      11.0
2020-01-14       NaN      12.0
```

And I think this is a perfectly natural situation for series for historic and forecasted values; there's no reason why there should ***not*** be a visual gap between them. Now, one way to visually remedy this could be to include the forecasted value of `6.0` at index `2020-01-08` for the `historic` series, ***or*** the historic value of 8 at index `2020-01-08` for the forecasts. You can do so using `df['forecast'].loc['2020-01-07']=8.0` or `df['historic'].loc['2020-01-08']=6.0`. This can of course be done more smoothly by programmatically determining the inserted value and the index. But here's the result either way:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


sns.set_style("darkgrid")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
#sns.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
%matplotlib inline

df_historic = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range("20200101", periods=7),
                            'historic': [1,2,3,3,6,4,8]}).set_index('dates')

df_forecast = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range("20200108", periods=7),
                            'forecast': [6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}).set_index('dates')

df=pd.merge(df_historic, df_forecast, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

#df['forecast'].loc['2020-01-07']=8.0
df['historic'].loc['2020-01-08']=6.0

for column in df.columns:
    g=sns.lineplot(x=df.index, y=df[column])

g.set_xticklabels(labels=df.index, rotation=-20)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you vestland. I added a bit of infromation which i can publish. Does that help? How can I remedy this visualization? I calculated by hand and the values are true.

Comment: @ShuFFle2207 I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: @ShuFFle2207 Are you using matplotlib here? Plotly perhaps?

Comment: I just seaborn to plot. matplib inline is in thw bwginning also.

Comment: @ShuFFle2207 Ah, yes I see the `sns` part of your code now. I'll take a look.

Comment: Especially your statement thath this is natural helepd me a lot. Thank you vestland.

Comment: @ShuFFle2207 No problem!